# How to get intellisense working in Xcode?

Tags: xcode, macos

In Visual Studio, I'm use to typing '.' for the intellisense window to open. This would list the available member variables and methods.

In Xcode, there's an extra step by pressing '.', then Command+Spacebar (or hitting Escape), and the intellisense window will open. This gets repetitive really quick.

My preference is to have the list open when pressing down '.'. Is there a solution?

Comment: Don't you get this by specifying the first letter of the attribute your looking for?  That is '.s' for example

Comment: Wow.. didn't know that. I guess it helps if you know the start of a method/variable that you're looking for.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is repetitive and annoying. So I use Ctrl+[.] right after pressing [.] instead of Command+Space, because it is just faster, since your finger is already over the [.]. Also Ctrl+[.] allows you to quickly iterate through available options.